# Overleaf no longer compiling anything with a link - no table of contents, no cross-references, no citations

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, citing, compiling, compilation-error

I have a report due in an hour and I cant seem to fix my Overleaf. Everything was fine and then I noticed that even though I had a citation present in my `references.bib` file (imported through Mendeley), I couldn't get the citation to appear in the code.

When I compiled the document, suddenly all links were gone - even those that I used as hyper references to refer to tables/sections/figures, and the entire table of contents is also blank. The cross references are appearing as ?? even though the labels have been defined and the `hyperref` package has been loaded. The citations which would normally be (Kim and Oh 2012) are now in bold with the file name as Kim2012papername.

I unlinked and re-linked Mendeley, deleted cache from Overleaf, cleared all browsing data and cookies from my browser, re-uploaded the `references.bib` file but nothing seems to work. The worst part is that it's just not compiling this project, every other project compiles just fine. I also tried making a copy of the file but the same issue persists. I also tried re-loading and compiling an earlier version of the file and now it doesn't compile that either.

I'm really worried, I don't know what to do. Any ideas on what can be fixed?

Comment: Install LaTeX on your computer?  Normally, I would delete the aux file and run it twice, but don't kkonw how to do that with overleaf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try "Recompile from scratch" under the compile option.  If this doesn't improve anything, check the log file for errors, there is likely something wrong in your code and it may well be flagged in the log.  Diagnosing without code is hard, try commenting out most of your document and recompiling from scratch, then uncommenting code to localise the error.

Comment: @DaiBowen Hi I tried recompiling from scratch and it didn't work. I checked the log files and all it says over and over again is that the citation doesnt exist or the label doesnt exist when they do, and the citation keys match as well.

Comment: @neth0609 you can try installing and running latex locally, but most likely there's an error cropping up somewhere in your code.  If it's not apparent in the logs, try commenting out sections and recompiling from scratch out until you have some references (`\ref`/`\label`) working.  It's probably worth commenting out the bibliography (this will break all `\cite`s, but not `\ref` commands), in case a faulty bib entry is to blame.  With an idea of what code is causing the problem it may be possible to offer more help.

Comment: @DaiBowen Fixed it! You were absolutely correct. One of the more recent citations I added had a corrupt .bib file. Removed it from mendeley, re-synced the bibliography and everything is back to normal. Only ended up getting here because of commenting sections out and trying to compile over and over again. Thank you all!

Comment: @neth0609 Great, my impression through this site is Mendeley (on top of [being](https://eighty-twenty.org/2018/06/13/mendeley-encrypted-db) [Mendeley](https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/mendeley_import#mendeley_database_encryption)) seems somewhat prone to producing dodgy bib entries, although that may be garbage in/garbage out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by a problem that cannot be reproduced, as it was due to an unseen malformed bib entry that has now been resolved in the comments.